# How to separate hex string in Java based on bits?

Tags: java, binary, hex

I am having some trouble attempting to separate a hex string into different parts based on some given amount of bits.

For example, let's say I have a string "400a3b" and I would like to break it down to 3 parts based on a specified bits. The three parts being a tag, an index, and an block offset in that order from left to right:

[TAG][INDEX][BLOCK]

Let's say the specified index amount is 3 bits and the block offset is 4 bits. How could I "extract" those specific parts of the hex string?

Comment: Do you want to extracts Tag="01000000000011000",Index="011" and Block="1101" from  a string "400a3b" ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm currently attempting to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My plan to extract therr parts from hex strings.

1) convert hex string to Long.

2) extract three parts by bit-wise operators, "&" (bit-wise and) and ">>" (bit-wise shift right).

Code:

```
char* hexStr;
Long original, tag, index,block;

hexStr =  "400a3b";  /* This is hex string to be processed */

original = Long.parseLong(hexStr, 16); /* Long converted from hex string */

tag = (original & 0xFFFF80) >> 7; /* mask higher 17 bits , then shift right 7 bits for TAG */
index = (original & 0x000070) >>4; /* mask 18 to 20 bits , then shift right 4 bit for INDEX */
block = original & 0x00000F; /* mask 21-24 bits for BLOCK */
```

How to know the masks and shift in various pattern of data:

(Following part is the answer for Kevin's comment to my answer.)

To know the masks and shift, let make bit-arrangement of data.
If the data has 2bits of index and 10bits of block, the rest 52 bits are tag.

I use 't' to represent the bit using for tag, 'i' for index and 'b' for block.

In 2bits index and 10bits block case, bit arrangement of data is as follows

```
ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttiibbbbbbbbbb // 52 't's, 2 'i's and 10 'b's.
```

To obtain the mask for tag, replace 't' to 1 , 'i' to 0 and 'b' to 0.

```
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000
```

That is the mask for tag and it can be represents by hexdecimal as FFFFFFFFFFFFF000.

There are 12 zeros in the right of ones, so shift right 12 bits are necessary.

In same way, masks for index and that for block are

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000  // 0000000000000C00
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111  // 00000000000003FF
```

and shift for index is 10. For block, it is not necessary to shift.

Is it clear enough?

Comment: So this is similar to how I originally did it, however, the hex string was just an example. It could be "f33500cb1" or it could be "35d3" so I'm not sure how to implement the mask in those situations.

Comment: If maximum number of characters in the hex string is less or equal to 16, replace "0xFFFF80" to "0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF80" is enough. If maximum number of characters in the hex strings exceeds 16, the code may become much complex, because no data type of java cannot contains integer number of more than 64 bits.

Comment: How do I implement the mask if I'm unsure of how many bits are required for the index and block offset? It could be 2 bits for index and 10 bits for block offset or 10 bits for index and 1 block offset bit or any given number for those two bits.

Comment: I cannot explain how to make masks within the characters limit of comment, so I will modify my answer.